# How to Redirect with primefaces polling?

Tags: jsf, redirect, jsf-2, primefaces, polling

I'm developing jsf with primefaces 5.0, I need to redirect user to another page if condition is satisfied in the backing bean. So I use `p:poll` to let the page check the condition every second, if the condition is met, redirect user to another page.

I create a small project to try this scenario, which using poll to check whether `int cnt` is >= 10, if so, redirect user to `welcomePrimefaces.xhtml`. Also, there's another thread `T1` which is used to simply increase `cnt` so that the condition may satisfied some time.

Here's what I've done:
**Page:**(Nothing special, just poll every second to check the status)

```
<h:form>
    Hello from Facelets
    <br />
    <p:poll interval="1" listener="#{mainBean.checkStatus()}"/>
</h:form>
```

**Backing Bean:**

```
public class MainBean {

    private Integer cnt = 0;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new T1(), "test");
        t1.start();

    }

    public void checkStatus() {
        synchronized (cnt) {
            System.out.println("cnt:" + cnt);
            if (cnt >= 10) {
                try {
                    Object request = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
                    Object response = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
                    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
                    HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
                    httpResponse.sendRedirect(httpRequest.getContextPath()
                            + "/welcomePrimefaces.xhtml");
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Error!");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class T1 implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    synchronized (cnt) {
                        cnt++;
                    }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println("Thread Error!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result is the `cnt` being printed 10 times(from 0 to 9), and after that, it is stocked, not even the polling executed.
So what's wrong with my code? Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not send the redirect from the Http response, but from the external context itself:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
        .redirect("welcomePrimefaces.xhtml");
```

Your code would properly work if the request wasn't partial (Ajax). The Mojarra JSF wrapper handles both of the cases, so just utilize it and don't overcomplicate yourself. Here you have its internal implementation in Mojarra 2.1.28:

**ExternalContextImpl.java**

```
/**
 * @see ExternalContext#redirect(String)
 */
public void redirect(String requestURI) throws IOException {

    FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    getELFlash().doLastPhaseActions(ctx, true);

    if (ctx.getPartialViewContext().isPartialRequest()) {
        //Handle partial request returning a redirection code in XML format
        if (getSession(true) instanceof HttpSession &&
            ctx.getResponseComplete()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        PartialResponseWriter pwriter;
        ResponseWriter writer = ctx.getResponseWriter();
        if (writer instanceof PartialResponseWriter) {
            pwriter = (PartialResponseWriter) writer;
        } else {
            pwriter = ctx.getPartialViewContext().getPartialResponseWriter();
        }
        setResponseContentType("text/xml");
        setResponseCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        addResponseHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        pwriter.startDocument();
        pwriter.redirect(requestURI);
        pwriter.endDocument();
    } else {
        //Standard redirection behaviour
        ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect(requestURI);
    }
    ctx.responseComplete();

}
```

Comment: "Don't overcomplicate yourself", that's exactly what you did I believe.

Comment: @SujanSivagurunathan, the answer is the first code piece. The second code piece belongs to the Mojarra implementation, I attached it just to show how it differs between ajax and non-ajax requests.

Comment: then it's the shortest possible answer. Sorry, I thought the redirect method was your own implementation.

Comment: Thank you @Xtreme Biker. So when I called the `redirect` method in my `checkStatus`, it actually re-render the whole page, right? If so,will the URL change?

Comment: @nosnhoj a redirection always changes the url in the browser address bar. What you're doing here follows [POST-REDIRECT-GET pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).